# Css is lost when initialize is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my problem, I am quite new to rails. I have a controller. but when I add an initialize() method to that class, all the css is gone. 
In another words I have a MovieController. Everything works as expected, but as soon as I add a new initialize method all the style of the page is gone. Any Idea.?

Thanks.
Jossie.

Comment: Why would you add initialize() in a controller? As far as I know controllers are suppose to deal with the requested actions.

Comment: @SybariteManoj, No answer for that , I just want to try that thats it .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails uses initialize internally. If you override default behaviour will not be carried out. So use `before_filter` to initialize something in controller
Example:

```
  before_filter :my_initialization

  private
    def my_initialization
      #do here
    end
```